# Rmarkdown displays unwanted output on pdf starting with ##

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have been using `Rmarkdown` for some time. I recently was generating my pdf output from `Rmarkdown`. I used the `ggplot` function from `ggplot2` and `sapply` to plot charts. While the charts got populated perfectly fine, There were bunch of other details that got plotted on the pdf.
Starting with ##, multiple lines with detail on panel plots data color size got printed. I am not sure how to exclude them from my plot. Is this related to `Rmarkdown` or `sapply`. I tried various options like echo=false but had no success.

[image: output image]

```
`sapply(unique(turnDatC$vintage),function(x) {
tmpflt <- filter(turnDatC,vintage == x)
sapply(unique(tmpflt$net_coupon),function(y) {
df1 <-filter(tmpflt,(net_coupon == y)) %>%
select(product,as_of_date,vintage, net_coupon,cltv_bkt,variable,value) %>%
group_by(product,vintage,net_coupon,cltv_bkt,variable) %>%
filter(length(value)>1) %>%
ungroup()
if(nrow(df1)>1)
{ print(x)
print(y)
plot(df1%>%
ggplot(aes(x = as_of_date,y = value,color = variable,group =    variable)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point() +
scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("months"),labels = date_format("%Y/%m")) +
xlab("TimeSeries") +
ylab("CPR") +
facet_grid(cltv_bkt ~ .) +
theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank(),     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
ggtitle(paste0("Vintage - ",x, " Coupon - ",y , " CLTV across Time Series")))}
})`
```

Comment: Please show an image of the problem output and the code that caused it

Comment: added code and output.thanks

Comment: have you set `results = "hide"` in the chunk options

Comment: thanks a lot results = "hide" solves the issue, however I was using results ="as is" for pagebreak in the chunk. Introducing hide will remove pagebreaks

Comment: Perhaps split the chunk into two chunks. Or wrap any function that is having output printed with `invisible()`

Comment: I basically used combination of invisible and as is to solve the issue. Thanks for all the help.